# How to set the focus on the open app after switching virtual desktop

Tags: windows-11, virtual-desktop

How can I set the focus to the app of the current virtual desktop on Windows11 ?

For example:
I have 2 virtual Desktops, 1 desktop where I have my Code-Editor open as well as the browser showing my website. The second virtual desktop has a browser window with a tutorial video.

What I now want is, that wenn I switch from desktop 1, where I have my code editor focused to desktop 2, that the video is focused to be able to just press space to start the video.

What actually happens is, that the focus is still on desktop 1 code editor and pressing space will add spaces to my code, which is ridiculous.

Comment: This is happening to me, I agree it's ridiculous!